# Can I post someone else's sandbox challenge?

Tags: discussion

ETHproductions made [this perfectly cromulent sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/12398#12398) but hasn't touched it in a week. Is it poor form to move it to the main site for him/her? (And then immediately post my own solution?)

Comment: Hmm cromulent... Nice word :D

Comment: I think this has happened multiple times before. Immediately posting your own solution isn't recommended though (something I learned the hard way...).

Comment: On topic: If you ask, and ETHproductioms says it's fine, then you can. You must get his/her permission first, though

Comment: @BetaDecay Worthy of an answer I think.